# htaccess redirect all url to same location except one starting with staging

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all url to one static page except for one that contains staging

for e.g.

base_url shoud land to /static/index.html

but:

base_url/anything should redirect to /f/w/anything

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^staging
RewriteRule ^(.*) static/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negation in `RewriteRule` itself:

```
RewriteRule !^staging static/index.html [L,NC]
```

btw `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` should have a starting slash so you condition should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/staging
```

---

**Update:** Based on edited question you can do:

```
RewriteEngine on

# landing page
RewriteRule ^/?$ static/index.html [L]

# other URLs
RewriteRule !^f/w/ f/w%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What can i do to show static page on base_url and other should work as it is?

Comment: You mean you want to show static page for `http://domain.com/` only and keep other URLs unchanged?

Comment: yes thats what i want, other will use base_url/anything should redirect to /f/w/anything